# How can I create a new spreadsheet with value-pasted specific sheets from another spreadsheet with a Vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I've been trying to find information about this on the web to try it on my own, but I have not found it.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 16 sheets, and I want a Vba code which creates a new spreadsheet and pastes in values specific sheets of my 16-sheets spreadsheet.

Could anyone help me?

Lot of thanks.

Comment: I've found a code on a recorded macro but its too long to put it here, how can I show it?

Comment: You can copy-paste it to the text and press CTRL-k to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather broad; in general, you can do this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
```

...to add a new sheet and this:

```
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy

Sheets(2).Paste Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)
```

..to copy and paste things.